# keep template's shape in different browser size on pc

Tags: css, protostar

Is that possible to keep away website of browser size changes like decrease browser size or restore down on pc or laptop?
I wanna keep my website's shape in one shape in pc or laptop when user change the size of browser.
For instance, if user decrease the size of browser, show up some scroll or something like this.
I'm using default joomla template  Protostar.
My desire is attached by screenshots. :([image]

[image]

Comment: It is not easy to follow you on your question and screenshots - but likely, if I understand right, you need different templates/styles per devices, or what? There is a plugin https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/digi-template-switch-pro/ that you can use for this.

Answer (score 2):

If you change the media queries from `min-width` to `min-device-width`, and `max-width` to `max-device-width` in `/templates/protostar/css/template.css` then this would probably do what you are after.  This should apply the responsive behaviours based on screen width and not browser window width.

You can do this under Extensions > Templates > Templates > Protostar Files > CSS > template.css

Note that this is only in the media query bit, ie `@media (max-width: 767px) {` and not where `min-width` or `max-width` is a style being applied  and not a media query.

It is important to point out that changing core files is not recommended, as future patching may over-write your changes.  However, since you can update that file in the admin, and it doesn't create an override, I'm unsure whether Joomla may actually think this is an okay thing to do.

I have to say, it sounds a bad idea to be doing this at all.  A fully responsive site is a good thing!

Comment: Richard I've found seven "@media min and max-width"
in template.css. I've changed the them, all of em. nothing happened.
I don't know, which one would be change! I've thought about your last sentence. Maybe it's better to give it up man.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a reason why you don't want the site to change depending on the screen size? Responsiveness of a website is very important in this day and age. If you do however want a complete static website it would be better to create your own template rather than try and override all the Protostar styling.
You could create a new template based off Protostar but remove all the media queries and go from there.